# Definitions/Use of Principal Bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I have come across two seemingly disparate definitions of a principal $G$-bundle, and would like some comments on the merits of each one and how this links to the general use of principal bundles in geometry, since I have only encountered this concept recently.

The first is a definition given here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalBundle.html. Specifically, a principal bundle is defined as a special case of a fiber bundle, where the fibers are groups and the group acts freely on the fibers.

The second is one due to Dominic Joyce found in his book *Riemannian Holonomy Groups and Calibrated Geometry*:
Let $M$ be a manifold, and $G$ a Lie group. A *principal bundle $P$ over $M$ with fibre $G$* is a manifold $P$ equiped with a smooth projection $\pi : P \to M,$ and an action of $G$ on $P$, which we will write as $p \mapsto^{g} g \cdot p$, for $g \in G$ and $p \in P$. This $G$-action must be smooth and free, and the projection $\pi: P \to M$ must be a fibration, with fibres the orbits of the $G$-action, so that for each $m \in M$ the fibre $\pi^{-1}(m)$ is a copy of $G$.

Note that in the first definition there is no mention of fibrations - only fiber bundles - which makes the second definition slightly confusing in light of the first.

Comment: I guess could be misleading, but what is exactly that disturbing you in the second definition? It's true that he speaks about fibration, but right after says that for each m the fiber is a copy of G, so indeed it's a fiber bundle.

Comment: I guess that he even brought the notion of a fibration in in the first place, when he could have just invoked the notion of a fiber bundle. It just seems a bit heavy-handed.

Comment: I think it is and I wouldn't use this text as a first approach...

Comment: Thanks for reassurance - what text would you recommend for this purpose?

Comment: Also, if you wish to leave a book suggestion and a general comment about principal bundles, I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comment, both definitions are right, but the second as you pointed out is without any good reason a little bit heavy-handed. I'm not sure if you already have a back ground in Riemannian Geometry or not. If not I would suggest you to have a look to some standard book on Riemannian Geometry before starting. My suggestion would be Spivak.

After that you should propably go to Kobayashi, Nomizu [Foundations of Differential Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471157333) (which is a standard in the field) and I would also suggest you Sharpe, [Differential Geometry](https://books.google.pt/books/about/Differential_Geometry.html?id=Ytqs4xU5QKAC&redir_esc=y). After you gave a read on those probably you're ready for start with *Riemannian Holonomy Groups and Calibrated Geometry*.